# Getting error "pathname cannot be converted from utf-8 to current locale" while extracting a zip file in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 18.04, locale, zip, unzip, utf-8

When I am trying to unzip a file "Desktop.zip" I am getting below error as shown in figure:

[image: err_msg]

I have made this zip file in ubuntu 20.04. Then downgraded to 18.04 and tried to unzip here.

I am not able to understand what and why is this problem occuring.

Although I am able to extract by using terminal command:
$ unzip Desktop.zip

But not by GUI, I am interested to know how can I solve it, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command : unzip -I UTF-8 Desktop.zip

Above command worked for me:

> unzip -I (encoding) (FILE_PATH) -d (Destination)